# Significato di "girare storto a qualcuno"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Oggi è mercoledì e tocca spedire via posta il lavoro svolto e il programma da svolgere per la firma dell'ambasciatore. Se la passano bene a Madrid sa... Ah, dottore, si ricordi che l'ambasciatore è il capo missione inteso come 'servizio', eh... non come 'titolo'; da lui dipendiamo noi tutti in ogni senso. È il nostro Supremo Divino, e le gerarchie in questo lavoro sono legge, se lo ricordi. Ha l'ultima parola su tutto: orari (decidesse di farci lavorare venti ore non possiamo rifiutarci...), programmi e provvedimenti. Essendo il capo dell'Ambasciata ha compiti delicati, soprattutto quelli di riferire della politica della Spagna, e con i tempi che corrono... Se **gli gira storto** ci fa cambiare aria, dunque, il mercoledì faccio gli straordinari volentieri; e meno male che il martedì mi salva quell'oretta o due di tennis. A proposito, lei gioca?»

Il brano fa riferimento al lavoro da svolgere dai lavoratori dell'Istituto italiano di cultura di Barcellona nel 1958. Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "gli gira storto" che appare in questo passaggio. L'ho cercata alla voce "girare" di alcuni dizionari, incluso il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non l'ho trovata. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curiosamente non lo trovo su nessun dizionario, neppure sotto “storto”, ma è una costruzione abbastanza abituale (“a X gira storto”, quasi sempre costruito con un pronome: “mi, ti, gli gira storto”), con il senso che la persona in questione è di malumore o maldisposta verso qualcuno o qualcosa, e quindi ostile.

Questa espressione unisce uno dei sensi figurati di [“girare”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/girare1), presente in locuzioni come

> *se gli gira*, se gli viene l’estro; *secondo come gli gira, dipende da come gli gira*, dipende dal suo umore, dal capriccio, e sim.; *ti gira male?*, sei di cattivo umore?

e uno degli usi di [“storto”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/storto1), molto affine a quello che appare in “avere la luna storta” e soprattutto “guardare storto”.

Comment: Interessante anche il pendant positivo "gli gira dritto".